# Create regular fill mesh within a closed area - Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

This question might possibly not satisfy SE standards, but I would really need help and I am running out of time..

I need to create a regular mesh within a rectangle, sort of a texture, made of lines inclined at 45 and 135 degrees. I created a series of lines using the "Fusion tool", then put a rectangle in the middle, select both, `Pathfinder > cut`, but it does not work.

Here is a capture. I'd like all those lines to be cut outside the rectangle's borders.

[image]

Ideally, I would then need to do it here, to highlight the area under the curve:

[image]

where instead of the arrow, I'd like to insert a shadowed mesh to indicate it more explicitly.

Many thanks for the help..

Comment: Use shape builder. Pathfinder does not really work in cases where the drawing is amade with line priority (which includes nearly all technical sources).

Comment: @joojaa thanks a lot for taking the time to answer. Could you please elaborate a bit more ? I tried with the shape builder, but nothing happens. Also, by the name, why should I build a shape?

Comment: whatever you want to participate in shape building must be selected before you enter shape buildetr

Comment: @joojaa indeed I select both objects, but instead it looks like the rectangle disappears (looses its line thickness)

Comment: Yeah double click the tool and you can disable it changing stroke colors. Anyway its better to make a copy edit the copy in  another layer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like you want to make a Pattern to use as a fill.

1. Draw a single 45° line
2. Do *Object > Pattern > Make*
3. In the Pattern editor, edit one of the anchors so that the lines touch, and hit *Done* when you have finished.

[image]

4. Now draw a shape, and select the new pattern you made in the fill dropdown

[image]

Comment: Its better to not draw it this way. Its better ti draw it vertical or horisontal, then rotate the the pattern. then the likelihood of pattern gap on expansion or other becomes a no issue as the pattern can be huge in size in on direction. the other advantage of this is that same pattern can be at any angle

Comment: Hot to rotate the internal fill ? From the shading window, the angle variable is blocked.

Comment: @mEm - are you asking me?  The angle is already 45 degrees. No need to rotate anything.

Comment: More to @joojaa since he commented specifically on that.

Comment: Ok, @BillyKerr, how to apply both 45 and 135 degrees patterns ? I am able to only select one.. not that I could not do that, but if possible, both would be better

Comment: OK, I managed to create a pattern from two lines at 45 and 135 degrees.

Comment: @BillyKerr last thing if you don't mind. How could I retrieve the pattern I created in a file into another one? Are they saved somewhere?
I'm sorry if I sound so dumb..

Comment: @mEm - you can just edit the pattern and add another line, as many lines or elements as you want. [see example](https://imgur.com/DusExUs).   Patterns are saved to the document they are used in. So, you can just copy the object with the pattern fill, and paste in another document, and the pattern will come with it.

Comment: @mEm take the rotate tool into use alt click on rotation center a menu appears; or rmb and choose rotate. In the menu then disable all other than pattern